Missing HTML 5 in VS Code Emmet listing
In VS Code, when I am in an html page (for instance test.html) I used to see html 5 (and another for xhtml) as an option when I start typing html.  Now I see only html.  This only gives me  rather than the html, head, body, etc tags in a starting template.

It happened when I tried to remove various highlightings in my user settings.json file.  But, I have removed all those settings and my html 5 option still has not come back.  It is extremely frustrating. I do not really want to reinstall.
On another computer, I had a fresh install of VS Code and saw the html 5 option.  As soon as I copied my user settings into that VS Code, I no longer saw the html 5 option.  So I know it is in my user settings.  I tried commenting suspect lines out and could not fix it - I tried setting suspect lines to true rather than false - no luck.  So then tried deleting my user settings which is supposed to reset them to default.  But it did not fix the issue.
Does anyone know why I would only be getting html and not html 5?  And how to fix it.

Is your setting Editor: Snippet Suggestions set to none?  And Editor  > Suggest: Show Snippets enabled?

thanks for the thoughts @mark but no difference.  They were not there.  I added them and the same as the screenshot.  I changed it to inline rather than none and the same as the screenshot.  I saved, closed and opened again.  Same as screen shot - missing the html 5 option.
